# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, как оформить предложения?

Зачем, говорит, все рассказываешь?

Знахарь махнул рукой, публикуй, мол, что хочешь.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что это тема неявной прямой речи, когда нераспространенные слова автора могут быть оформлены в виде вводного предложения. Тогда получается:

(1)Зачем, говорит, все рассказываешь? (2)Знахарь махнул рукой - публикуй, мол, что хочешь. Это БСП, лучше поставить тире для обозначения паузы (присоединение с изъяснительным значением).

ОТВЕТ 2.

Двоеточие имеет три основных значения (пояснение, изъяснение и следственно-причинная связь), во всех трех значениях двоеточие можно заменить тире, но замену нужно объяснить. В приведенном примере мы имеем ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение. Если поставим двоеточие, то в тексте надо делать предупредительную паузу-остановку, в случае  тире присоединительная пауза короче, что соответствует структуре данного текста. Поэтому, если быть точным, в данных предложениях значение ИЗЪЯСНЕНИЯ выражается с помощью ПРЕДУПРЕДИТЕЛЬНОГО ДВОЕТОЧИЯ или ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОГО ТИРЕ.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с Софией.

Зачем, говорит, все рассказываешь?-запятые выделяют вводное слово

Во втором предложении возможны варианты:

Знахарь махнул рукой: публикуй, мол, что хочешь.- второе предл. разъясняет содержание первого (знак знахаря означал разрешение публиковать).

Тире тоже возможно: Знахарь махнул рукой - (и это означало" публикуй, мол, что хочешь").- значение присоединения тоже имеется, но раскрытие содержания, по-моему,приоритетно. Хотя сейчас пунктуация упрощается, двоеточие и тире часто заменяют друг друга.

Comment: Скорее не друг друга, а тире заменяет двоеточие.

Comment: Да нет, бывает, что и двоеточие вместо тире, даже в классике:"Делать было нечего:Марья Ивановна села в карету и поехала во дворец"(Пушкин.Следствие, а здесь не тире)Мелкий дождь сеет с утра: выйти невозможно(Тургенев).-следствие.

Comment: Сейчас уже говорят: "причинно-следственные связи обозначаются на письме тире и двоеточием". Вот и выбирайте.